# Order of axis style options in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to understand in which order axis options are applied, and what overwrites what (in the case I'm using `style` and not `append style`).

When a style is redefined, the previous options should be overwritten, exept for `post` which seems to work like `append`. I noticed that #4 is always ignored, even if it's the only one, and that #1 and #2 override #3 but if I delete # then #2 and #3 works together. So what's the hiearchy between the two keys in the different positions?

PS: I checked the manual on page 361/... but it's still unclear to me

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.style={...},        %1
  every axis post/.style{...},    %2
}

\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every axis/.style={...},      %3
    every axis post/.style={...}, %4
  ]
  \begin{axis}[ ... ]             %5
  \addplot {x};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

After some experiments, it looks like:

- options in #4 are always ignored
- options in #3 are applied first
- options in #1 override ALL options in #3
- options in #2 are appended to #1 and #3
- options in #5 are appended to all other options

Is that correct? Shouldn't local options (#3 and #4) have an higher priority on global options (#1 and #2)? What's the best practice (considering `append style` too) for defining a global style for my document and a local style for the picture (which may contan more `axis` environments)?

EDIT: what's the best solution (with or without `post` and `append`) to globally set `x|y axis line style` (thickness, ...) with `\pgfplotsset` and locally set `axis x|y line` (which overrides `axis x|y line style` settings)?

Comment: As for `%3` and `%4`: you need to prepend `/pgfplots/` to make it work. As for `%1` and `%2`, these are global options, while `%5` are local.

Comment: Thank you. Options in `%3` work even withour `/pgfplots/`. If I put `/pgfplots/` does the priority change?

Comment: Yes, this will change all `tikz` options because you are in the `tikz` path. However, options specific to pgfplots will be ignored or lead to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree to a large extent with what you wrote except that I believe that in their current form options `%3` and `%4` have no effect if these are `pgfplots` options. This is because, if you pass options to the `tikzpicture` environment, you are in the `tikz` "directory". You can change the path by prepending `/pgfplots/`. If you do that, these options will be implemented in the full `tikzpicture`, i.e. in every axis within. You may call them hence "semi-local". On the other hand, the `\pgfplots{...}` options automatically are in the "right path" for pgfplots. And they are global while those in `\begin{axis}[...]` apply to the respective axis only, and might be called "local" (without "semi"). This is illustrated by the following MWE, in which I kick out all `post` options because they do not add any information on locality (and because I do not see myself going through 5!=120 options ;-).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{A/.style={color=blue},
B/.style={color=red},
C/.style={color=green!60!black}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style=A}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style=B]
  \begin{axis}[C,title={ABC}]             
  \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style=B}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style=A]
  \begin{axis}[C,title={BAC}]             
  \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style=B}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style=C]
  \begin{axis}[A,title={BCA}]             
  \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style=A}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style=C]
  \begin{axis}[B,title={ACB}]             
  \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style=C}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style=A]
  \begin{axis}[B,title={CAB}]             
  \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 &
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style=C}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/every axis/.style=B]
  \begin{axis}[A,title={CBA}]             
  \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, with `pgfplots` the behaviour of the "semilocal" styles makes more sense. So the order from lowest to highest priority should be [1-3]-[5]-[2-4], where (a) the options with higher priority are appended to the options with lower priority and (b) 3 overrides 1 and 4 overrides 2. Is that right?

Comment: @Taekwondavide I do not quite understand why you lump `1-3` together and so on. But it is true that options that get imposed last override previous options, and (semi-)local options only affect things in the same group.These are the main principles which allowed me so far to understand what's going on.  Normally local options are imposed last. (I have seen `\globaldefs=1` being used in order to "globalize" local options, but I would recommend not to use these things unless you know 100% what you are doing. There are also `smuggle` commands in Ti*k*Z but I never understood or used them.)

Comment: I lumped them because it looks like in the groups 1-3 and 2-4 the latter overrides the former, while the prevailing one of each group is appended to the others without overriding them. For example, if I give 1245  I obtain 1+5+4 (by increasing locality/priority). But I'm not sure as I didn't try all the possible combinations.

Comment: Example: 1 = red dotted, 2 = green dashed, 4 = blue, 5 = no marks. The result should be dotted+no marks+blue (from 1, red is overridden by blue and dotted is kept; both options of 2 are completely overridden by 4 and dashed is not kept)

Comment: @Taekwondavide I get the expected result: If I use your template, the axis is green and dashed, and the plot is blue and has no marks. Note that `blue` here has nothing to do with the options of the `tikzpicture`. It is just a default value. You can check this by using `red` instead. If I prepend the options of the `tikzpicture` by `/pgfplots/` , then the axis will become blue, as expected. (The plot will still be blue, but this is just the default value.